# AST: check if two nodes are connected

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I am parsing some code as below. I get a list of `ast.node`. Now, I want to know which nodes are linked to which node. Is it possible to do that?

Example in below code: 1st assign is not connected (`f = lambda..`) to any other assign. But 2nd assign and `FunctioDef` are connected. Is it possible to infer this from some node attribute?

Assuming of course there is no other definition or code outside this.

```
code = '''
f = lambda x : x
factor = 2
def f(arg):
    if arg == 0:
        return 1
    return factor*arg*f(arg-1)
    
'''


parsed = ast.parse(code)


>>> parsed.body
[<_ast.Assign at 0x7f9c81f0e670>,
 <_ast.Assign at 0x7f9c92042070>,
 <_ast.FunctionDef at 0x7f9c920421f0>]
```

Comment: Why is the second assign connected and the first one isn't?

Comment: Firstassign is `f = lambda...`, second assign is `factor = 2`. `factor` is used in `FunctionDef`, so 2nd is connected to `Funcdef`. But first one is not cause`FunctionDef` actually overwrites `f`. So, `FunctionDef` does not need `f` created by 1st assign.

Comment: Well, so you need to go inside the `FunctionDef` and analyse the names it references and determine which previous assignments have defined these names.

Comment: But note that `f` will use whatever `factor` refers to at the time it is called, not at the time it is defined. So actually the second assignment and the function definition aren't connected at all.

Comment: yes, I agree with that on `factor`. But I am assuming this is all the code. And there are no definitions outside of this code.

By going inside `FunctionDef`, you mean doing `ast.walk` on `FunctionDef` gathering all `id` attributes from node and check their previous definitions? Seems like very long way to do it, i was hoping there was easier way to infer this from `ast.node`